# Angular 7 reactive forms - select position in a Form Build array

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, formbuilder, angular2-formbuilder

I need to select the position in the controls for the form builder array.

I need to do this: testArray.controls[0] but get a console error.

It works fine for testArray.controls. But that doesnt allow me to select a specific index in the form array

**Component HTML:**

```
   <div formArrayName="formArray">

         <div *ngFor="let item of testArray.controls[0]; let i = index" 
         [formGroupName]="i">

         </div>

    </div>
```

**Component TS:**

```
  public item = {
    field: [ '', [ Validators.required ] ]
  };

  public createForm(): void 
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      formArray:  this.fb.array([ this.createItem() ]),
    });
  }

  get testArray(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('formArray') as FormArray;
  }

  public createItem(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group(this.item);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can, you just can't do it from *within* that for loop. When you're within the loop, you are already at the individual item level.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-access-form-control-array?file=src/app/app.component.ts)'s a working stackblitz that demonstrates the idea, but the concept is this:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <div formArrayName="formArray">
    <h2> As array</h2>
    <div *ngFor="let item of testArray.controls; let i = index">
      <input formControlName="{{i}}"> Item value: {{ item.value }}
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Individually, get the second item</h2>
      <input [formControl]="testArray.controls[1]"> Item value: {{ item.value }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to use formControlName as im using a theming system

Comment: `formControlName` for the single node? Not sure if that's possible out of the box. Lemme try figuring it out.

Comment: @AngularM this won't be possible out of the box. If you look at angular docs, it says explicitly _Syncs a FormControl in an existing **FormGroup** to a form control element by name._ (emphasys mine). You could look into how formControlName directive works: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular/8.0.0/packages/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_control_name.ts, then try to create your own version, but this would be very fiddly, I assume. I'm pretty sure there's an easier way, though. You say you have "a theming system". What exactly do you need for that system to work?